# Windows batch command to encrypt multiple PGP files

Tags: batch-file, pgp

I am trying to encrypt multiple files into pgp. Right now I have a windows batch  script that it only works if all files are listed in the script individually

```
"path%\pgp.exe  --encrypt filename_%TodayDate%.text  --recipient "KEY"
"path%\pgp.exe  --encrypt filename2_%TodayDate%.text  --recipient "KEY"
"path%\pgp.exe  --encrypt filename3_%TodayDate%.text  --recipient "KEY"
```

Goal is to encrypt all files that are ".*txt" and ".csv" file in the same folder. 
 Is it possible for pgp ?

Comment: Looks like Windows and CMD.EXE.

Comment: does your  `pgpapplication.exe` allow for wildcard characters and multiple file args?  if not, have you considered writing a `*.bat` file (assuming this is windows) to loop through the list of `*.txt` and `*.csv` files?

Comment: @markp - ill double check - right now it is a windows batch file

Comment: @ceving correct

Comment: my WIndows/batch programming skills are very basic (ie, I spend most of my time in Unix/Linux) but there's surely a means of looping through a list of files based on a wildcard pattern (eg, *.txt *.csv) ... as opposed to hardcoding the filenames in the *bat file ... ?

Comment: Better yet, stop being deliberately awkward, and tell us the exact name, and if necessary version, of the application you're calling, `pgpapplication.exe`.

Comment: Actually is pgp.exe (pgp application)  - 10.4.2.22 version

Comment: GNU PGP works the same on Windows and Linux as far as I remember.  So this isn't a Windows Specific issue.

Comment: Take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: use [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) to loop over your files (and bookmark [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt) for future reference).